# AD FS sign-in page doesn't show up after logout if Service Workers are enabled

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, service-worker, create-react-app, adfs3.0

I have a web application built in ASP.Net core 2.2 with React js as the client app.
This web is using service worker (provided by CRA- create-react-app) to cache my application shell (static resources like JS, CSS, etc).
Also, AD FS (Active Directory Federated Service) is integrated to the ASP.Net core app to authenticate my users.

**Now the problem statement:**
When I navigate to my home url (e.g. https://directory-mysite.com/) the AD FS sign-in page doesn't show up after the user has logged out. When I do CTRL+F5 then it works.
This is happening due to the service worker caching my home url and not bypassing the request to the network (my server).

**Question:**
I want to know if there is any way I can fix this problem.
Disabling the service worker is not the option and editing seems to be a challenge since the app is in the CRA shell.

Comment: Well, of course there is a way to fix it :) But you didn't provide your Service Worker code so it's very difficult to help you. Attach your production SW code!

Comment: @pate: My app is in the shell of CRA and the SW code is managed by it. There is no customization done yet.

Comment: try to append a timestamp (date in ms) to your home url like  https://directory-mysite.com`/?ts=1582883860779` in order to disable caching

Comment: @pero_hero: Thanks for your input. But I am not sure if that can be controlled since the users will enter the Url in the browser and moreover, this is a PWA which once added to the user's home screen, will always open the home Url (static url) by itself.